# Are my definitions for devfs, devtmpfs and udev in Linux right?

Tags: linux, udev, devices

I would like to know if my definitions of devfs, devtmpfs and udev in Linux are clear and accurate.

`devfs` is the kernel implementation of `/dev` [Deprecated]. Does this get populated by the kernel like the case for`devtempfs`? According to @Gilles [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/236901/233788) yes it does. Then both `devfs` and `devtempfs` hardcode names of devices.

`devtempfs` is a temporary file system that that gets populated with device files by the kernel and is mounted on `/dev`.

`udev` is a daemon that listens to the kernel's uevents and matches the attributes of those uevents against certain predefined rules to perform device initialization, make useful symlinks, etc...

The current Linux implementation of `/dev` is `devtempfs` + `udev`.

What is right and what is wrong in my definitions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty much correct on `udev` and `devtmpfs`, with the caveat that `udev` is not required (pretty much, if you have no devices that need special handling from userspace and don't need the symlinks, you don't technically *need* `udev`).

As far as `devfs`, I think you're correct, but I'm not 100% certain.  As a general rule, unless you're dealing with 10+ year old Linux systems (or poorly designed embedded devices), you don't have to worry about `devfs`.

Comment: It seems like `devfs` is the same as `devtmpfs` in that device files are dynamically populated by the kernel.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/161674/5132 for `udev`.

Comment: Just to mention that ``devfs`` has been [obsoleted](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/process/changes.rst?id=562f36ed28e6faa4245ea2ca1392d90ab98ebbe8#n126) in Linux kernel 4.16, so technically we are now left with ``devtmpfs`` + ``udev`` (if needed).