# udev: how to wait for a specific device to appear from a shell script

Tags: linux, udev, embedded

I have an embedded system with a tiny initramfs which needs to mount an overlayfs over the rootfs partition and switch_root to the new merged filesystem.

It's just a couple operations run from the init shell script so I don't want to pull in the entire systemd infrastructure but I want to make sure all relevant block devices are already present in the system or wait for them to appear. I added the systemd-udevd component to my initramfs (considering even switching to eudev if I can get the same results).

I was unable to find any examples or figure out how to use udevadm to block and wait until a specific device appears. It seems to me that some combination of udevadm trigger and settle should do it, but no combination seemed to work in my case.

I can easily code it using libudev in C or pyudev in Python, but I guess there should be a way to achieve that using existing tools.

I would prefer to avoid some busy waiting with manual checking if given file exists already.

Comment: `udevadm monitor` will output new devices as they appear, so you can pipe that into some script, but typically if you are running udev you should set up a rule to run the script when the device is matched by the rule. see `man 7 udev`.

Comment: There are a few `systemd-udev` alternatives (e.g. `mdev`, `eu-dev` etc) that may be more appropriate for space constrained devices and nice list of them can be seen in a [Are there alternatives to using `udev` Unix Stack Exchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/379062/109111) .